# read typescript class member inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, oop

This is my code :

```
    export class CustomToast implements OnInit {
            toastTypeGroup: string;
            message: string;
            title: string; 
            showDuration= "300";

            constructor(_toastTypeGroup: string, _message:string, _title: string ){
                this.toastTypeGroup = _toastTypeGroup;
                this.message = _message;
                this.title =  _title;
            }

            ngOnInit() {
                **//this is the solution** 
                **var _this = this;**
                console.log(this.showDuration);
                var ToastrDemo = function () {
                    var toastr: any = (<any>window).toastr;
                    var k, m = -1, f = 0;

                    var t = function () {
                        var t, o,
                            //toastTypeGroup
                            e = this.toastTypeGroup,
                            //message
                            n = this.message,
                            //title
                            a = this.title,
                            //showDuration
                            i = this.showDuration,
                    };

                    return { init: function () { t() } }
                }();jQuery(document).ready(function () { ToastrDemo.init() });

            }



        }
```

My problem is that I want to **read members values** from my class called CustomToast **inside my JavaScript** function called var t = function () {...}.

I can't get **typescript class member value** *inside* a JavaScript Function. 
e.g "toastTypeGroup" member is not accessible iside my fucntion
This is the big problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try with an arrow callbacks: `let ToastrDemo = () => { ... let t = () => { ... } };`, `return { init: () => { t() } }` and `jQuery(document).ready(() => { ToastrDemo.init() });`. In short, replace every occurrence of `function()` with `() =>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: thanks guys.

I just moved this line " var _this = this; " before to call ToastrDemo function.

and I already update my post to the right behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
var _this = this;
```

to the beginning of ngOnInit and use `_this.showDuration` or use `bind(this)`

Comment: thanks guys.

I just moved this line " var _this = this; " before to call ToastrDemo function.

and I already update my post to the right behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question but wouldn't you just add `.bind(this)` to your definition of `t`?

```
var t = function () {
    var t, o,
        //toastTypeGroup
        e = this.toastTypeGroup,
        //message
        n = this.message,
        //title
        a = this.title,
        //showDuration
        i = this.showDuration,
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: not working!
may be because T fucntion it's inside var ToastrDemo = function () {..}
what do u think ?

Comment: thanks guys.

I just moved this line " var _this = this; " before to call ToastrDemo function.

and I already update my post to the right behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
/** @type {your type} */
var _this = this;
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html

Comment: thanks guys.

I just moved this line " var _this = this; " before to call ToastrDemo function.

and I already update my post to the right behaviour.